# Why does WebStorm look so different on different device

Tags: ide, settings, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just got a new PC and installed WebStorm the same way I did on my laptop, but it looks way different and I'm not sure why. When I try to enable settings on my laptop I don't see it, while I do see it on my PC, but I need to enable it on my laptop.

How can I get the settings of my laptop?

PC IDE
[image: Pc IDE]

Laptop IDE
[image: Laptop IDE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **New UI** (currently in Beta) that JetBrains is trying to promote (to get more feedback to polish it before making it the main one).

You must have 2022.3 version or newer to be able to use the New UI.

You can switch it ON or OFF at `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | New UI` (requires IDE restart)

[image]